# The visual tip of a pgf arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In the 'Defining New Arrow Tip Kinds' chapter in the PGF part of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a, the *visual tip end* of an arrow tip is defined as (p. 1016)

> the counterpart of the visual back end for the front.

The *visual back end*, in turn, is defined as follows. (ibid.)

> The *visual back end* is the position where the path and the the arrow head “meet last” on the path.

To illustrate these and other concepts, the following picture is given.

[image: An arrow tip.]

In terms of this illustration, the visual back end is said to be at (-2,0), and the visual tip end is said to be at (1,0).

I understand the definition of *visual back end*, but not that of *visual tip end*. Going by the definitions quoted above ('the visual tip end is the counterpart of the visual back end'), the visual tip end would be the position where the path and the arrow head "meet first" on the path, but this would be somewhere on the x-axis between -3 and -2, not at (1,0).

I'll appreciate it if someone can give a straightforward definition of *visual tip end*, without referring to the definition of *visual back end*, and explain, based on this definition, why the visual tip end in the above illustration is at (1,0).

Comment: I don't think the use of "counterpart" is very clear here, especially paired with this picture. What would happen if you used this arrow *head* as a *tail*? Or in the middle of a line? (no chance to test here, but it would be the last point to make contact)

Comment: The word "counterpart" means that when the arrow is reversed (for example `->` becomes `-<`), the new visual back end is negative the old visual tip end.

Comment: @Symbol1: But you seem to assume that if -> becomes -< then the pointed part would just touch the line, but why do you make this assumption? Why isn't it possible that, when reversed, the pointed part intrudes into the line?

Comment: @ChrisH: But doesn't it depend on how much the line will coincide with the tail?

Comment: Possibly. Which is why I added the question about the middle.

Comment: @ChrisH: OK, I think I understand. This is a good answer. If you write it is an answer, emphasizing the 'using the arrow in the middle of the line', I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't actually know what the answer is for certain - that's just a guess. But if you don't get anything more definitive I'll write something.

Comment: @ChrisH: If you do end up writing an answer, please also take note of the last paragraph in my post.

Comment: If you think of the path as you head towards the head of the arrow, then `(1,0)` is the first point at which the tip meats the path and `(-2,0)` is the last point. The tip doesn't meet the path between `(-3,0)` and `(-2,0)` because the shape of the tip is such that there's no intersection with the path. At least, that's how I've understood it. Possibly misunderstood it. Probably misunderstood it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term `visual back end` does not necessarily refer to any geometric point on the arrowhead. It is merely a **parameter** provided to arrow designers.

The motivation to define `visual back end` in addition to `back end` is clear only if we consider curved path

[image]

In this case, the arrow looks ugly because it does not lie on the path. We expect Ti*k*Z to slightly rotate the arrow. For example:

[image]

This looks a lot better as the `visual back end` lies on the solid red line. The `bending` library will do this job for you with the option `flex`.

One may also try

[image]

This looks good too as the `back end`(green dot) lies on the solid red line. The `bending` library will do this job for you with the option `flex'`.

---

<del>The motivation to define `visual tip end` is the same: when one writes `-{Stealth[reversed]}`, the library needs the coordinate of the `visual back end` for this reversed arrow. In this case, the `visual tip end` of `Stealth` will be used.</del>

So far I told only half of the story. knowing that the arrow's `visual tip end`/ `back end` lies on the original path does not determine the placement of the arrowhead. The following is what Ti*k*Z does when `flex=1` is used:

- shift the arrowhead so that `visual tip end` coincides the endpoint of the path;
- rotate the arrowhead so that the `visual back end` lies on the path.

Therefore, similar to what I said at the beginning of the answer, `visual tip end` does not necessarily represent any geometric point. It is the arrowhead-designer's choice to assign a point as the `visual tip end`, which will later be used by Ti*k*Z to position the arrowhead.

---

Appendix

Figures above are generated by acquiring the source code of the manual. In particular `pgfmanual-en-base-arrows.tex` line 108-117. As one can easily see, the code draws the path and arrowhead separately.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red!50, ,line width=1cm] (0,0) -- (4,0);
  \path [tips, opacity=.25,line width=1cm, -{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm, inset=1cm]}] (0,0) -- (6,0);

  \draw [->,thick] (1,0) -- (8,0) node [right] {$x$-axis};
  \draw [->,thick] (5,-2.25) -- (5,2.25) node [above] {$y$-axis};

  \foreach \i in {-3,-2,-1,1,2} \draw (\i+5,-1mm) -- (\i+5,1mm) node [above] {\small$\i$};
  \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (49mm,\i) -- (51mm,\i) node [right] {\small$\i$};;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red!50, ,line width=1cm] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \draw [red] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \path [tips, opacity=.25,line width=1cm, -{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm, inset=1cm]}] (0,0) -- (6,0);

  \draw [->,thick] (1,0) -- (8,0) node [right] {$x$-axis};
  \draw [->,thick] (5,-2.25) -- (5,2.25) node [above] {$y$-axis};

  \foreach \i in {-3,-2,-1,1,2} \draw (\i+5,-1mm) -- (\i+5,1mm) node [above] {\small$\i$};
  \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (49mm,\i) -- (51mm,\i) node [right] {\small$\i$};;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red!50, ,line width=1cm] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \draw [red] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \path [tips, opacity=.25,line width=1cm, -{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm, inset=1cm]}] (0,-.6) -- (6,0);

  \draw [->,thick] (1,0) -- (8,0) node [right] {$x$-axis};
  \draw [->,thick] (5,-2.25) -- (5,2.25) node [above] {$y$-axis};

  \foreach \i in {-3,-2,-1,1,2} \draw (\i+5,-1mm) -- (\i+5,1mm) node [above] {\small$\i$};
  \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (49mm,\i) -- (51mm,\i) node [right] {\small$\i$};;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red!50, ,line width=1cm] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \draw [red] (0,-4) to[bend left] (4,0);
  \path [tips, opacity=.25,line width=1cm, -{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm, inset=1cm]}] (0,-1.3) -- (6,0);
  \fill[green]($(6,0)!4cm!(0,-1.3)$)circle(.1);

  \draw [->,thick] (1,0) -- (8,0) node [right] {$x$-axis};
  \draw [->,thick] (5,-2.25) -- (5,2.25) node [above] {$y$-axis};

  \foreach \i in {-3,-2,-1,1,2} \draw (\i+5,-1mm) -- (\i+5,1mm) node [above] {\small$\i$};
  \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (49mm,\i) -- (51mm,\i) node [right] {\small$\i$};;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red!50, ,line width=1cm] (0,0) -- (4,0);
  \path [tips, opacity=.25,line width=1cm, -{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm, inset=1cm,reversed]}] (0,0) -- (6,0);

  \draw [->,thick] (1,0) -- (8,0) node [right] {$x$-axis};
  \draw [->,thick] (5,-2.25) -- (5,2.25) node [above] {$y$-axis};

  \foreach \i in {-3,-2,-1,1,2} \draw (\i+5,-1mm) -- (\i+5,1mm) node [above] {\small$\i$};
  \foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (49mm,\i) -- (51mm,\i) node [right] {\small$\i$};;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.25,scale=5]
  \draw [red,line width=1cm,-{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm,inset=1cm,flex=0]},preaction={draw,-}]
  (-1,-.5) .. controls (0,-.5) and (0,0) .. (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.25,scale=5]
  \draw [red,line width=1cm,-{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm,inset=1cm,flex=1]},preaction={draw,-}]
  (-1,-.5) .. controls (0,-.5) and (0,0) .. (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.25,scale=5]
  \draw [red,line width=1cm,-{Stealth[black,line width=0pt,length=4cm, width=4cm,inset=1cm,flex'=1]},preaction={draw,-}]
  (-1,-.5) .. controls (0,-.5) and (0,0) .. (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: PS. It should not be the case that `(1,0)` is the center of the rotation. Please do not assume this. The center of rotation is yet another question. The point made here is the reference point for performing the rotation.

Comment: Could you please, for further investigation, also post the source Tikz codes producing those very good drawings, or at least explain where to find the source you amended ?

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer. I hate to say it, but, as I wrote in my question, I understand what *visual back end* means; it is the meaning of *visual tip end* that I was after. Your answer leaves this point to an afterthought in the last paragraph, and is therefore not answering my question.

Comment: @marsupilam see the appendix :)

Comment: @EvanAad Long story short: `visual tip end` is the endpoint of the original path. See also my update.

Comment: You wrote that when flex=1 is used, TikZ (1) shifts the arrowhead so that visual tip end coincides with the endpoint of the path; (2) rotates the arrowhead so that the visual back end lies on the path. Is the visual tip end the axis of this rotation?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, otherwise we would not see that the visual tip end coincides the endpoint of the path.

Comment: @Symbol1: Yeah, I noticed it a couple seconds before you posted your reply, and then I deleted my comment, so now your answer is dangling... Sorry.